# “Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'” path issues

Tags: java, cmd, jvm

I am new to Java. I have a problem regarding trying to run java in command prompt but it display this message:

“Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'”

However, such path is not even exist and even if I tried uninstall Java Runtime Environment, it still display the same message. Even more confusing, I have read some of the solution, but such file like 'java.exe' or 'javaw.exe' in C:\Windows\System32 is not even there. Please help...

Comment: How can one help you if nobody knows, what you have tried?
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See also [Error: could not open 'C:\Java\jre8\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'](http://www.java67.com/2015/10/error-could-not-open-java-jmv-cfg-lib-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall your current version
2. Go to your system drive (C drive most of the time) and search for `java`
3. Delete all the .exe files which comes from the search result (should be three of them: `java.exe`, `javaw.exe`, `javaws.exe`)
4. Now download from Oracle and install the *jre* again.

Note: Although 9 is out i would still recommend 8 because 9 is still not compatible with many IDEs.